# WPF Automaticly list Items from Context

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, itemtemplate

Let's say I have a class *A*. I already created a UserControle *X* that uses *A* as DataContext. Now there is Class *B*. Class *B* contains nothing but a List filled with instances of *A*. An Instance of *B* is the DataContext of my current View.

What's the best way to show for all Instances of A in the list of the current DataContext a Usercontrole X?

Do I need a Value Converter? Or is there an easier way.

I tried to keep it abstract. If I need to specify certain things please let me know.

Comment: Use an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate`? Bind the `ItemsControl` to the collection and add the `UserControl` to the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Use an ItemsControl (or ListBox if items should be selectable) that has X in its ItemTemplate. Make sure X does not explicitly set its own DataContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate`. Bind the `ItemsControl` to the public collection property, and add the `UserControl` to the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheListProperty}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- The UserControl will inherit the current item in 'TheListProperty' as its DataContext -->
            <local:UserControlX />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Make sure that you don't explicitly set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`. It should inherit its `DataContext` from the current item in the `ItemsControl`.